# Jupyter notebook kernel dies when I run a simple cluster model

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, k-means

I just tried to run a simple KMeans model. I ran the code line by line, too. It always goes die on the "fitting step". What might be the reason for this issue? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
X= np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
km= KMeans(n_clusters=2)
km.fit(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just set base(root) in the navigator